# Container not respecting exit status from process

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, bamboo

I am confused to how the exit code from a process inside a container gets passed to docker.
I have a container which runs an npm run script.
The npm run script fails with exit status 1 but it seems that the exit status is not passed to the docker process itself because Bamboo flags the build task as success.

```sh
30-Sep-2019 15:43:53    npm ERR! Exit status 1
30-Sep-2019 15:43:53    npm ERR!
30-Sep-2019 15:43:53    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
30-Sep-2019 15:43:53    
30-Sep-2019 15:43:53    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
30-Sep-2019 15:43:53    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-30T13_43_53_321Z-debug.log
30-Sep-2019 15:43:54    Stopping containers 
30-Sep-2019 15:43:54    b3efbe0710cc
30-Sep-2019 15:43:54    Removing containers
30-Sep-2019 15:43:55    b3efbe0710cc
30-Sep-2019 15:43:55    Finished task 'Script' with result: Success
```

The container is started with the docker runcommand.

```
docker run -e GIT_REPO=${bamboo_repository_git_repositoryUrl} -e RELEASE_VERSION=${bamboo.release_version} wc-release:1.0.0
```

Where the dockerfile of the release container is as such:

```
FROM node:12

ENV RELEASE_VERSION=${VERSION}
ENV GIT_REPO=${REPO}

ENV http_proxy=http://***
ENV https_proxy=http://***

COPY .npmrc /root/.npmrc
COPY .gitconfig /root/.gitconfig
COPY .git-credentials /root/.git-credentials

WORKDIR /home/node/app

ENTRYPOINT git clone ${GIT_REPO} /home/node/app && npm install && npm run release:prepare && npm run release:testless -- ${RELEASE_VERSION}
```

Any advice?
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  This depends on things like, for example, whether you're directly running `CMD ["npm", "run"]` or there's an intermediate shell script involved.

Comment: @DavidMaze updated the question.

Comment: try to explore solutions to similar issue from this thread https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bamboo needs to be sent an explicit exit code, this can be achieved by using `set -e` in the bash script. You will get something like this:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -e
docker run -e GIT_REPO=${bamboo_repository_git_repositoryUrl} -e RELEASE_VERSION=${bamboo.release_version} wc-release:1.0.0
```